# Using .minmax to return values only when min is in lower index position of an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, minmax

Is there a way to only return the min/max values of an array where the min is in a lower index position than the max?

For instance, let's say we have:

```
array = [10, 12, 5, 3, 20, 1, 9]
```

If we did .minmax on this array we would get the following:

```
array.minmax
=> [1, 20]
```

However, I'm only interested in getting the minimum value that has a lower index than the maximum value, in this case:

```
=> [3, 20]
```

I've been trying to think about different ways to do this but haven't had much luck. I tried to find a way to get the min/max values where the difference between the two returns a negative value but couldn't find a way to do that.

**Edit**: To clarify, this is essentially intended to be a stock picker. The array elements are the prices of a stock each day. I'm interested in maximizing the difference between a min/max in the array (buy on the day when stock = 3, sell on the day when stock = 15). The values may not be the absolute min or max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

```
array[0..array.index(array.max)].minmax
```

So just apply minmax to the elements between the first of the array and the index of the maximum.

To return the index values, just use map to iterate through the minmax array and get their indexes in a new array:

```
array         = [10, 12, 5, 3, 20, 1, 9]
min_max_array = array[0..array.index(array.max)].minmax
min_max_index = min_max_array.map{|v| array.index(v)}
```

Comment: This is simple and appears to be just what I'm looking for. Do you happen to know if this also allows for the ability to return the index position of said values?

Comment: What about if the max value occurs more than once though? For `[10, 12, 5, 3, 20, 1, 9, 20]` your solution will return `[3, 20]` and not `[1, 20]`.

Comment: @scobo you'd just have to define whether you wanted the maximum value found to be the one that occurs first or last. You can find the index of the last occurrence with something like: array.size - array.reverse.index(20) - 1

Comment: Thanks @DavidAldridge. Doing something like `array.rindex(array.max)` seems like it would work as well, in case we didn't initially know the values that would be in the array.

Comment: Actually, @DavidAldridge I've found an issue. Let's say the array was `array = [17,3,6,9,15,8,6,1,10]`. This returns `[17, 17]` instead of `[3, 15]`

Comment: Can you define the logic whereby it returns [3, 15]? 15 is not the maximum value.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Just made an edit to the original for clarification. My original could have been phrased a little better. I'm not looking for the absolute min/max but rather the points at which the difference between the sequential min/max is greatest. Does that make sense?

Comment: What about for [10, 9, 8 ,7, 6, 5]?

Comment: I guess in a case like that, there would be no 'buy'. So if set up correctly, it would return an error/nil.

Comment: I think what you'd want to do is similar to this method, but run the above algorithm for all the subsets of the array from indexes [0..-1], [1..-1], [2..-1] up to [array.size-2..-1] to see which one you get the maximum for. Then that starting index will give you the index of the min.